# Gitlab runner stucks while pulling docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce, gitlab-runner

I was trying to run my gitlab-ci in my hosted gitlab server and I picked docker for gitlab-runner executer but in pipline it got stucked and doesn't work.
What should I do to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a fix?  I'm seeing the same issue on mine.  My runners are EC2 instances, with images stored in ECR.  I can pull the images on the machines, so that rules out permissions / connectivity.  I think it's a problem with the GitLab runner.

Comment: It turns out something was causing a kernel panic and crashing the instance.  I didn't have the bandwidth to find the root cause, but updating to a newer base AMI fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the same issue, the Machine on which the docker is running, is sitting behind a proxy server, which is why its getting stuck when its trying to pull the image.

If you are able to login to the machine and check the internet access..
Check if you are using some kind of proxy or not?
Your ID may have SSO to Proxy and hence your ID works .. if the gitlab-runner service runs on a different account, that account may not have internet access